# Enrich their food menus?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Villagers used to have A B C as food, now there is one more food option D for them. In this case, can I say: 1)***D enriches villagers' food menus?*** 2) ***D enriches villagers' food options?***

Which one is more natural to native speakers?
Thank you.

Comment: _Menu_ normally refers specifically to a written list of food choices, so it's not particularly appropriate when speaking of people with a limited diet. How about **increases villagers' food options**?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my British English opinion:

A menu is what you would expect to be given when you enter a restaurant.

Your question referred to "food" rather than entire meal options so I presume we're talking about some remote tribe, rather than a more advanced society.

Of the two options presented, no.2 seems more appropriate if I am inferring the context correctly. I would also add the word "the" before "villagers'"

You could also consider "D enriches **the** villagers' [dietary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dietary) options"